# Splitting Multiple LESS arguments

Tags: css, less, mixins

I have this mixin:

```
.gradient(@alpha, ...) {
    @r: extract(@arguments,1);
    @g: extract(@arguments,2);
    @b: extract(@arguments,3);

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(@r,@g, @b, .2) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(@r,@g, @b, .2)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,@alpha)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(@r,@g, @b, .2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(@r,@g, @b, .2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(@r,@g, @b, .2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(@r,@g, @b, .2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
}
```

Setting color and alpha:

```
@rgbColor: 221,73,50;
@gradientAlpha: 0.3;
```

Using it:

```
.wrapper .gradient { .gradient( @gradientAlpha, @rgbColor ); }
```

Returns:

```
SyntaxError: error evaluating function `rgba`: color functions take numbers as parameters
```

Seems to work perfectly fine until I add the extra alpha param. I've been scouring the web for 24hrs but can't find anything that explains why this error would creep up. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Much appreciated!

EDIT:

As per seven-phrases-max in the comments, I tried the following:

```
.gradient(...) {
    @color: extract(@arguments,1);
    @alpha: extract(@arguments,2);

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  fade(@color, .2) 0%, color(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,fade(@color, .2)), color-stop(100%,fade(0,0,0,@alpha)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  fade(@color, .2) 0%,fade(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  fade(@color, .2) 0%,fade(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  fade(@color, .2) 0%,fade(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  fade(@color, .2) 0%,fade(0,0,0,@alpha) 100%);
}

@myColor: 221,73,50;
@gradientAlpha: 30%;

.wrapper .gradient { .gradient(@myColor, @gradientAlpha); }
```

But this returns the following error:

```
SyntaxError: error evaluating function `fade`: Object #<Object> has no method 'toHSL'
```

Comment: In your example `@arguments` is actually a two-dimensional array as it includes both `@gradientAlpha` and `@rgbColor` values and the latter is an array too (so `extract(@arguments,2);` actually returns `221,73,50` value). To achieve what you want use [named variadic parameter](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-parametric-feature-advanced-arguments-and-the-coderestcode-variable) instead e.g.: `.gradient(@alpha, @whatever...)`.

Comment: Regardless of above discover the [`fade`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#color-operations-fade) function which provides more straight-forward method to apply a transparency to a color value, i.e. no need to disintegrate colors to r, g, b components and then reintegrate it via `rgba`). E.g. `fade(#000, 50%)` creates `rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)` CSS value.

Comment: @seven-phases-max thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion and got a different error, please see my edit above. Thanks!

Comment: Well, about your edits, no - not this way. **1.** Why you do you need varadic arguments there at all? I can't see any need for it, define the mixin just as `.gradient(@color, @alpha) {` **2.** `221,73,50` is not a color value. Use `@myColor: rgb(221, 73, 50);` or `@myColor: #dd4932;` instead. **3.** `fade(0, 0, 0, @alpha)` is also incorrect, use `fade(#000, @alpha)`.